# Error : Undefined variable: data in view (foreach)

Tags: laravel

I have this error appearing while I try to submit a registering form :

> (2/2) ErrorException Undefined variable: langues

And Languages is a multi-select option.

Here are my codes :

register_patient.blade.php :

```
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control tc-select" name="langues[]" multiple="multiple" required  data-placeholder="@lang('Langues')" >
                <option ></option>
                      @foreach ($langues as $langue)
                        <option value="{{ $langue->id }}" {{ (collect(old('langues'))->contains($langue->id)) ? 'selected':'' }}>{{ __($langue->name) }}</option>
                      @endforeach
                    </select>
                     @if ($errors->has('langues'))
                          <span class="help-block">
                              <strong>{{ $errors->first('langues') }}</strong>
                          </span>
                      @endif
              </div>
```

---

web.php

```
Route::get('/inscription-client-avocat-om', 'RegisterController@register')->name('register.patient');
```

---

RegisterController.php

```
public function register()
{

    $langues = Langue::all();
    $specialites = Specialite::all();
    $etablissements = Etablissement::all();
    $secteurs = Secteur::all();
    return view('auth.register_patient',['secteurs'=>$secteurs,'langues' => $langues,'specialites' =>$specialites,'etablissements'=> $etablissements]);
}
```

Comment: langues not languages ?

Comment: Sorry the error is the following :ErrorException
Undefined variable: langues (View: /var/www/html/Laravel/resources/views/auth/register.blade.php)

Comment: so the error is in `/resources/views/auth/register.blade.php` not in `register_patient.blade.php`.?

Comment: Yes... And I don't even know why but the formular page is coming from register_patient.blade.php.  Once the page is submitted, it shows this error about another view : register.blade.php : and this page is a page for the registration of another kind of user.